# how to get null records also in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can't I use `SET ANSI NULL` in my normal parametrize query. In fact I want to take out records `where first_name='Rupesh' or NULL` but I am getting only the Rupesh name records.

I have a stored procedure otherwise I could set `set ansi null off` and could get all records...

What should I do now?

Comment: put the sql statement you're executing in the question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where first_name is null or first_name = 'Rupesh'
```

Comment: could you tell me what is the role of set ansi null in the stored proceure

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
where isnull(first_name, 'Rupesh') = 'Rupesh'
```